# Testing Entity Framework 3.5

Tags: c#, unit-testing, entity-framework

What is the best way to write Unit-tests when I'm limited to EF 3.5 entities?

Comment: What are you trying to unit testing? Can you provide more info on what it is that you are trying to do or are having problems with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to unit test your queries themselves, I would strongly recommend just setting up a test database and testing them with real data.  Using `IObjectSet<T>` in order to substitute an in-memory collection for your unit tests to run against is a BAD idea.  There are differences between how a linq query is run under linq-to-objects, and how it's parsed into a T-SQL command, namely in how nulls are handled.  For example,

```
db.People.Where(p => p.AccountNum == variable);
```

If that's using linq-to-objects (as in some memory object set you've subbed in as a replacement for `IObjectSet<T>` for your unit tests) then that will run perfectly.  If however you're running that against a database, then if variable is null, your query will break, since a query of

```
WHERE [peopleTableAlias].[AccountNum] = @param1
```

will be generated, with @param1 being null, which will be worthless, since you really need an IS NULL query generated.

---

If however you want to test your business logic, which calls your EF datacontext, then I would say to wrap up those queries into DataAccess objects, mark your methods as virtual, inject said DAOs where they're needed, and in your unit tests substitute either manual mocks which override those methods to return the desired value for your tests, or else do the same thing with your favorite mocking framework (ie, Rhino).

**EDIT** - sorry, `IObjectSet<T>` is limited to EF4, which you don't have, obviously.  But since using that for your unit tests is something I recommended *not* doing, the answer should still apply.

Comment: The class I'm going to test is a DAL. So setting up a test db seems like the right way to go. Do u have any good tips about using a test db or anything I need to be aware of?

Comment: The main thing is cleaning up after yourself after each test, so data from one test doesn't interfere with the next.  You can manually delete your test data between tests, obviously, but I've also read about using a TransactionScope to surround your test, and then rolling it back instead of committing it after the test, to prevent the data from actually sticking to the DB.  I haven't ever tried that though, so I can't say how well it works